# Angular: Add ngClick from js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, addeventlistener, angularjs-ng-click

I am developing small web page for mobile devices with Angular. 
I want to toggle click listener for whole page like

```
$('.page').on('click',...);
$('.page').off('click',...);
```

but in Angular way. And I don't want to use `ng-Click` with some conditions because most of the time the click should not work, it is just for error handling. Is it possible or I need to user pure js/jQuery?

Panel HTML:

```
<div class="alert error" ng-show="errorMessage">
    <div class="alert-text">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what conditions you need to bind/unbind the event listener?

Comment: If some error happens then panel with error description will be shown and click listener should be bind. After click the panel will be disappear and event should be unbind.

Comment: So this is something that is only related to this panel. can you show the markup of this panel?

Comment: Of course, if it is only related with the panel I'd just add ngClick on this panel. But I have requirement to close the panel after click on any place in page

Comment: just show your panel html

Comment: `<div class="alert error" ng-show="errorMessage">
    <div class="alert-text">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I created a directive:

- It should be used in conjunction with `ngIf`.
- `ngIf` should refer to an assignable variable on the scope
- For example don't do this: `ng-if='myFunc()'`  *or*  `ng-if='var1 || var2'`

here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fmNH2PbRrruRqGFYiui1?p=preview

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('errorBox', function($document, $parse){
  return {
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs) {
      var clickHandler = function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
           $parse(attrs.ngIf).assign(scope.$parent,'')
        })
        $document.off('click', clickHandler);
      };

      $document.on('click', clickHandler)
    }
  }
});
```

**html:**

```
<div ng-if="errorMessage" error-box class="alert error">
  <div class="alert-text">{{ errorMessage }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a $scope variable that keeps track if it's 'allowed' to click. Then you can do something like this

```
<div ng-click="isDisabled || yourAction()"></div>
```