# How do I dynamically add a ng-pattern attribute to an html element?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a multi-purpose modal dialog in my app with one text input.
Sometimes I need just any text, sometimes I want to restrict the text to match a regex pattern.

I tried adding the regex with jQuery `attr` like this:

```
$("#popupTextInput").attr("ng-pattern", "/.*imdb\.com\/title\/.*/");
```

Doesn't work. When I inspect the rendered element the correct `ng-pattern` directive appears on the element but the `formname.$valid` is always true, no matter what I enter.

When I manually add the attribute (with the exact same appearance in firebug) it works as expected.

Instead of a string with the pattern I also tried adding a regex pattern directly to the attribute like this:

```
var regexp = /.*imdb\.com\/title\/.*/;
$("#popupTextInput").attr("ng-pattern", regexp);
```

But that doesn't work either.

I am puzzled. Can anybody shed some light on this?
I should probably mention that I add the attribute **before** I create the modal.

ETA:
Did some further experiments. I tried having ng-pattern on the input by default and remove when not needed.
Something similar happened:
When I remove the ng-pattern it is removed from the element (at least inspection doesn't show it) but the regex pattern is still in effect.
I tried the $scope.$apply suggestion below (with and without function in $apply) but it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Try using `$scope.$apply();` just after using the jQuery.</s>

```
$scope.$apply( function() {
    $("#popupTextInput").attr("ng-pattern", "/.*imdb\.com\/title\/.*/");
});
```

It will cause your bindings to update and probably fix the problem.

To know more about it check out [Stack Overflow question on what $apply does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply) and [Jim Hoskin's article on $apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Okay after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457776/angular-add-ngclick-from-js)

I think the correct way to go about it would be.

```
parent = $("#popupTextInput").parent();
var newInput = $("#popupTextInput").clone();
$("#popupTextInput").remove();
newInput.attr("ng-pattern", "/.*imdb\.com\/title\/.*/");
var compiledElement = $compile(newInput)($scope);
parent.append(compiledElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work either.

Comment: `$scope.$apply()` should wrap the jQuery DOM manipulation(s): `$scope.$apply(function() { // what you want to apply});`

Comment: I did as suggested but this time the ng-pattern doesn't appear on the input at all.

Comment: Is it possible for you to have two inputs and disable and hide the appropriate one. Though it's still worth looking into dynamically adding ng-attributes.

Comment: Okay after digging around I think the correct method would be to use $compile before inserting into Angular.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the $compile? I already tried putting 2 inputs on the form and not showing one of them. That didn't work either. Only one shows but it's always the last one that is active.